ROS Noetic Windows Install Not Finding Package
I am trying to install ROS Noetic on a Windows PC using the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Windows.
After installing chocolatey, I am running the following command to install ROS Noetic:
choco upgrade ros-noetic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0
and I get the following errors:
Unable to connect to source 'https://aka.ms/ros/public':
 Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://ros.org/Packages()?$filter=(tolower(Id)%20eq%20'ros-noetic-desktop_full')%20and%20IsLatestVersion&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
ros-noetic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance. 

Is this no longer available to download from "https://aka.ms/ros/public" or is the site just down right now?  I was able to do install this version of ROS on another PC about a year and a half ago.  I tried running this command on that PC, and it also said it couldn't connect.
I have tried installing using the ros-noetic-dektop_full.nupkg I have on that older PC (by copying over on a flash drive), but am running into other issues with dependencies and permissions.
